# Error while using knitR with ESS

Tags: r, emacs, knitr

I messed up with something but I don't know where to look. My guess is that something happened when I updated some packages in `emacs` but I don't know which one exactly. Any help would be appreciated Even running a basic command like the following:

```
\begin{document}
<<test>>=
1+1
@ 
\end{document}
```

yield the following error

```
label: test
Quitting from lines 39-40 (/tmp/tmp.rnw) 
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 3, 0
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In is.na(res[, 1]) :
  is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
2: In is.na(res) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
```

and here is the stack trace:

```
+ Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 3, 0

---------------------------------- 

22: stop(gettextf("arguments imply differing number of rows: %s", 
        paste(unique(nrows), collapse = ", ")), domain = NA)
21: data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE)
20: cbind(deparse.level, ...)
19: cbind(z[, c("line1", "col1", "line2", "col2", "text")], merge_cmd(z, 
        markup))
18: (if (fallback) hi_naive else hilight_one)(code, format, markup, 
        escape_fun)
17: highr::hilight(x, format, prompt = options$prompt, markup = opts$markup)
16: hilight_source(x, "latex", options)
15: (knit_hooks$get("source"))(src, options)
14: wrap.source(X[[1L]], ...)
13: FUN(X[[1L]], ...)
12: lapply(x, wrap, options)
11: wrap.list(res, options)
10: wrap(res, options)
9: unlist(wrap(res, options))
8: block_exec(params)
7: call_block(x)
6: process_group.block(group)
5: process_group(group)
4: withCallingHandlers(if (tangle) process_tangle(group) else process_group(group), 
       error = function(e) {
           setwd(wd)
           cat(res, sep = "\n", file = output %n% "")
           message("Quitting from lines ", paste(current_lines(i), 
               collapse = "-"), " (", knit_concord$get("infile"), 
               ") ")
       })
3: process_file(text, output)
2: knit(input, output = output, envir = envir, quiet = quiet, encoding = encoding)
1: knit2pdf("tmp.rnw")
```

**Update**

```
   ## R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
## Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)

## locale:
##  [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.utf8       LC_NUMERIC=C             
##  [3] LC_TIME=en_US.utf8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.utf8    
##  [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.utf8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.utf8   
##  [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.utf8       LC_NAME=C                
##  [9] LC_ADDRESS=C              LC_TELEPHONE=C           
## [11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.utf8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C      

## attached base packages:
## [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

## other attached packages:
## [1] knitr_1.10.5

## loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
## [1] compiler_3.1.2 evaluate_0.7   formatR_1.2    highr_0.5      stringr_1.0.0 
## [6] tcltk_3.1.2    tools_3.1.2
```

Comment: `sessionInfo()`? All packages up-to-date?

Comment: @Yihui I have updated the built-in packages and put my sessionInfo() above. But the problem persists. Do you have lead to the problem?

Comment: @Yihui Updating the packages and restarting the session solved the problem. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Ran into the same problem today. For me this was fixed by upgrading the knitr packge from version 1.10.5 to version 1.11., the evaluate package from version 0.7 to version 0.7.2, the formatR package from version 0.9 to version 1.2, and the highr package from version 0.2.1 to version 0.5.

I upgraded these in order and it only worked after upgrading highr, so I suspect that this is the culprit.

Sigh, looks like it's probably time to update.packages().

Comment: I can confirm that the problem is present with knitr 1.11 and at least one version of highr lower than 0.5.1. But after upgrading highr to 0.5.1 the problem went away (with knitr 1.1 and R 3.2.2)

Comment: Same issue when I updated `knitr` to version `1.12` from `1.4.1`. 


Resolved when upgraded `highr` to `0.5.1` from `0.2`.